# How to Put a Value From a CHCSV Parser Array Into a Realm Object Property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I've implemented a CHCSV Parser and the delegate method for it returns an NSMutableArray called `currentRow` for each line of the source CSV file. If I NSLog the array after a line is parsed I can see that text items in the array are quoted and numbers (integers) are naked. The log output of `currentRow` looks like this: `("urgent_needs",0,0,0,1,"",YES,YES)`.

OK, so I need to get those values into a Realm data object, which is defined as follows:

```
@interface Tile : RLMObject
@property NSString *wordKey;
@property NSInteger pageNum;
@property NSInteger viewNum;
@property NSInteger viewItemNum;
@property NSInteger targetPageNum;
@property BOOL enqueue;
@property BOOL playAudio;
@property NSString *action;
@end
```

I use the following code to attempt setting the object's properties:

```
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [Tile createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"wordKey": currentRow[0],
                                           @"pageNum": currentRow[1],
                                           @"viewNum": currentRow[2],
                                           @"viewItemNum": currentRow[3],
                                           @"targetPageNum": currentRow[4],
                                           @"action": currentRow[5],
                                           @"enqueue": currentRow[6],
                                           @"playAudio": currentRow[7]}
     ];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

When I run this code i get the following exception:

```
Error adding data object: Invalid value '(0)' for property 'pageNum'
```

I've tried several ways of casting the array element, all to no avail. It seems to accept the first property's string data with no complaints. I suspect it's a simple solution but I'm stumped. I appreciate any ideas or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'(0)' is a string and pageNum is an integer. Try

```
@([currentRow[1] integerValue])
```

Edit: It appears your init method takes a dictionary and dictionaries need objects. You are going to have to go into the implementation of the method and have it use

```
[object[@"pageNum"] integerValue]
```

Comment: That was one of the things I tried. I get a error `"Collection element of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') is not an Objective-C object."`

Comment: You'll need to wrap that `NSInteger` in an `NSNumber`

Comment: I have it working doing what I think you (and @segiddins) suggested: `@"pageNum": [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[currentRow[1] integerValue]],`  I was thrown off by thinking that the values in the array were numbers not strings (because the text elements were quoted).

Comment: @bluesmoke glad to hear it, if my answer solved your problem you should mark it as the answer